# Puppet overwrites symlinked directory

Tags: linux, centos, puppet, configuration-management, puppet-agent

I am using Puppet to manage the configurations of some servers. One of the tasks is to create a specific folder structure under `/www` for hosting our applications.

But lately, we've had this server where `/www` is just a symbolic link to another directory (had to do that because of storage shortage)

```
$ ls -l /www
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Oct 25 15:33 /www -> /storage/www/
```

And we've been using this so far to manage directories:

```
file { $path:
ensure => directory,
owner  => user,
group  => group,
mode   => 'a=rx,u+w'
}
```

The issue with this specific server, is that when running Puppet, the `/www` symlink gets deleted and Puppet creates a new regular directory under `/www` instead. And that breaks the applications for us unless we intervene manually to create the symbolic link again.

**My question:**
Does someone know of a way that makes Puppet not delete the symlink and just treat it as a directory: If no `/www` directory or no `/www` symlink exists, create the `/www` directory, else do nothing?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is to change

```
file { $path:
    ensure => directory,
    owner  => user,
    group  => group,
    mode   => 'a=rx,u+w'
}
```

into

```
file { $path:
    ensure => link,
    target => /path/to/original/directory
    owner  => user,
    group  => group,
    mode   => 'a=rx,u+w'
}
```

By using `ensure => directory`, you are telling puppet that you want a directory, and that anything else it finds (like a file or symbolic link) it should clobber and replace with the directory. By using `ensure => link`, you'll be telling puppet that you want a symbolic link that points to the value of `target`, which in turn could be a directory, a file, or a device. Depending on what you're doing, you may need to create a file type (using `ensure => directory`) on your target, if you need puppet to manage it.

I would strongly recommend you read the documentation for the [file type](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/types/file.html) to better understand how to use it.

Edit:

To distinguish between different servers, you'll want to use individual [`node`](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_node_definitions.html) definitions for your different servers. You could essentially do the following to get what you want:

```
node 'server1.mydomain.com' {
    file { $path:
        ensure => directory,
        owner  => user,
        group  => group,
        mode   => 'a=rx,u+w'
    }
}

node 'server2.mydomain.com' {
    file { $path:
        ensure => link,
        target => /path/to/original/directory
        owner  => user,
        group  => group,
        mode   => 'a=rx,u+w'
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to have symbolic link on all the servers, The problem is,  `/www` is not always a symbolic link. On some servers, it's a regular directory, on others it's a symbolic link. Sometimes it does not exist at all and needs to be created.

Comment: The thing about puppet is that essentially its a state machine. You could create separate configurations for each server, but that adds a level of complexity that you will always have to maintain. One or two "exceptions" may not seem like much, but at some point a line has to be drawn.

Comment: @midihenry, I've updated my answer to address your concern.

Comment: Thanks, that might be a workaround in this case. But that does not really answer my question. So as far as I understand, there is no option in Puppet to just consider symbolic links to directories as directories. 
Just found this issue that describes my problem: https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/4394

Comment: You could do it with a single `file { $path : ...}` just use a variable for the `ensure` value that is set in the node/hiera/other.